# C# Code is unreachable

Tags: c#

I'm making this dll loader.  I can't seem to get it to return a false statement.

Just comment a fix with how you fixed it so I understand the way you fixed it?

It keeps saying: Code is unreachable.

It says it at the else statement

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}

internal class Program
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    static extern bool system(string str);

    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.Title = "Load DLL Test";

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.Write("CREATED BY TOXLP\n");
        Console.WriteLine("PLEASE TYPE A DLL NAME");
        Console.WriteLine("======================");

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("EXAMPLE:");
        Console.WriteLine("NAME.DLL");
        Console.WriteLine("======================");

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        var dllname = Console.ReadLine();
        var pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(dllname);

        if (pDll != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"LOADED!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"FAILED!");  
        }
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"FAILED!");  
        }
        system("pause");

Comment: You can't get compiler warnings on multiple lines. Also, what datatype is `pDll`? Is it a class or struct?

Comment: With your code posted, I can't reproduce the issue. Remember that a struct _must_ have a value, so it can never be null.

Comment: Structs can't be null.

Comment: @user3443278, "its a struct bro", is the most important piece of information for this question. `pDll` being a struct *(a value type)*, can't be null, therefore your `else` part would never be executed.

Comment: So for anyone else in this thread. Try out this code. I can understand why checking for null would not work, but I can't get a compiler warning.

Comment: For future reference, if you work out an answer to your own question, the right thing to do is to post it *as* an answer. Don't edit your *question* with either the fix or to say "Solved" - the way we know that questions have been answered on SO is if there's an accepted answer - which, specifically, is allowed to be your own if you so choose.

Comment: @gunr2171, you are right, I don't get any warning for comparing `IntPtr` with null.

Comment: Ah alright well sorry man am new here so i didn't know D: just clicked on answer for the solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `IntPtr` is a value type, not a reference hence it cannot be null. if you want to check if the pointer had never been set (meaning the operation had failed) you should check fo the pointer being Zero

```
ptr == IntPtr.Zero
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `var pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(dllname);` is returning a non-nullable object, e.g. a `struct`.  Therefore it can never by null.

You might want to check it is not `default` instead (*maybe*...)

Answer (score 0):

pDll != null is always True, that is why code is unreachable.
It cannot be False, 'cos if is not loaded pDll == IntPtr.Zero